# Trying to self-define a function to sort a vector of different kinds of elements

Tags: c++, sorting

I want to write a function somewhat like the sort in stl. This is part of my main function

```
inline bool myCmp(const int & a, const int & b) {
return a > b;
 }

 int main() {
int n, * s, i;
std::vector<int> v;
std::list<int> l;
std::cin >> n;
s = new int[n];
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    std::cin >> s[i];
    v.push_back(s[i]);
    l.push_back(s[i]);
}
mySort(v.begin(), v.end(), myCmp);
mySort(l.begin(), l.end());
```

and I implement mySort function here

```
    template <typename T>
typedef bool (*pf)(const T& ,const T&);
template <typename T>
void mySort(T a, T b, pf = nullptr)
{
  for(auto i = a; i != b; i++)
  {
    for(auto j = a + 1; j != b; j++)
    {
      if(i >  j)
      {
        T temp = i;
        i = j;
        j = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

unfortunately, I encounter some errors,

```
    sort.h: In instantiation of 'void mySort(T, T, pf) [with T = std::_List_iterator<int>; pf = bool (*)(const int&, const int&)]':
main.cpp:22:30:   required from here
sort.h:8:20: error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'std::_List_iterator<int>' and 'int')
     for(auto j = a + 1; j != b; j++)
                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:60,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:334:5: note: candidate: template<class _Iterator> std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator> std::operator+(typename std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::difference_type, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator+(typename reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::difference_type __n,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:334:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from main.cpp:4:0:
```

so what's wrong with the operator '+'?
and how can I successfully write this mySort function?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, in the line:

```
mySort(l.begin(), l.end());
```

and inside,

```
for(auto j = a + 1; j != b; j++)
             ^^^^^
```

you are trying to access `operator+` of the list iterator. But the iterator returned by `std::list<T>::begin/end` is a bidirectional iterator. Bidirectional iterators don't have `operator+` defined. You can use `operator++` though.

The `std::vector` on the other hand, returns a random access iterator by `std::vector<T>::begin/end`. Random access iterators do define `operator+`.

So, try something like this:

```
for(auto i = a; i != b; i++)
{
    auto c = a;

    for(auto j = ++c; j != b; j++)
    {
        ...
```